# Wanted Generate greetings automatically onload

Tags: javascript, html

I don't want the button to generate words on click I want the list to be toggle through the list of words whilst the page is loaded, like if it were a short animation clip! 
here is what i got so far

JS

```
let greeting= () => {
  let hello = ['¡Hola!', 'Ola!', 'Namaste', 'Hello', 'Bonjour','Zdravstvuyte','Nǐn hǎo','Konnichiwa','Anyoung haseyo','Goddag'];


  let name = hello[Math.floor(Math.random() * hello.length)]; 

  if( document.getElementById("name")){
    document.getElementById("placeholder"). removeChild(document.getElementById("name"));
  }
  let element = document.createElement("div");
    element.setAttribute("id", "name");
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
  document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(element)
  document.getElementById("placeholder").click(element)



}

greeting()
```

HTML

```
<section class="bg-dark text-white" onload="greeting()">
    <div id="placeholder" class=" text-center h1 " style="height:fit-content"></div>
   </section>
   <button  type ="button"class ="btn bg-dark text-white btn-block" onclick="greeting()">Press me!</button>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what's wrong?

Comment: Try placing the `onload` on the` HTML`, or add a scripted event for page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't attach an onload to a div. Typically onload is only used with the body tag.  With that said, you can just wrap a timer and start it.

```js
let greeting = () => {
  let hello = ['¡Hola!', 'Ola!', 'Namaste', 'Hello', 'Bonjour','Zdravstvuyte','Nǐn hǎo','Konnichiwa','Anyoung haseyo','Goddag'];


  let name = hello[Math.floor(Math.random() * hello.length)];

  if (document.getElementById("name")){
    document.getElementById("placeholder").removeChild(document.getElementById("name"));
  }
  
  let element = document.createElement("div");
    element.setAttribute("id", "name");
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
  document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(element)
  document.getElementById("placeholder").click(element)
}

let runGreeting = () => {
 setInterval(greeting, 2000);
};

runGreeting();
```

```html
<section class="bg-dark text-white">
    <div id="placeholder" class="text-center h1" style="height:fit-content">
      <div id="name"></div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

To have a function run on a timer, you can use the `setInterval` function described here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp